# Where does Maven store the source and javadocs when downloaded via the Eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using the Maven Eclipse plug-in to to add dependencies to my project. After setting a dependency, I right-clicked my project, selected Maven->Download Sources (and JavaDoc) but they were not automatically attached to the dependency's classes.  Where are the source code and JavaDoc files stored?

Note: this is my first day using Maven so my understanding of Download Sources may be way off.

Answer (score 13):

When you install maven it's default installation directory is `/usr/share/maven`

Inside this directory you have mvn executable, configurations etc. The file you are looking for is `/usr/share/maven/conf/settings.xml`

In this you have following default configuration

```
  <!-- localRepository
   | The path to the local repository maven will use to store artifacts.
   |
   | Default: ~/.m2/repository
  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
  -->
```

So by default all dependencies will be downloaded to `~/.m2/repository`. If you want to change this you can provide your path in

```
<localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
```

Answer (score 7):

if you don't have a `<localRepository>` entry under `<settings>` in your `settings.xml`, they will by default go in `$HOME/.m2`.  To specify a different location, add (or uncomment) localRepository:

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" 
          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">

  <localRepository>/path/to/local/repo</localRepository>
```

Answer (score 4):

By default, Maven should download dependencies sources and JavaDocs to its local repository. If you don't know where is your local Maven repository, check Maven **settings.xml** file [You can read more here](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/examples/attach-library-sources.html)

Comment: Thanks, I found maven repository and found the (defaulted) junit jar, source and JavaDoc but the source and JavaDoc for the commons-threadpool (the Dependency that I added myself) are not in the same folder as the threadpool jar.  Is it possible that the source/JavaDoc failed to download or is it more likely that I have config issues?   Note: I added the suggested plugin line to my pom file as your link suggested.

Comment: If maven is trying to download sources/javadocs and fails to do so there should be a relevant message on the eclipse maven console.

Comment: After downloading sources and javadoc I had to restart eclipse before eclipse registered the fresh javadoc tooltips